# Автоматическое разделение на страницы HTML содержимого

Tags: html, c++, qt

Собственно задача такова - отобразить HTML документ в виде одной или нескольких страниц A4 (зависит от документа). Нужно для печати и окна предварительного просмотра печати. Раньше пользовался `QWebView` вместе со стандартным диалогом просмотра печати - там текст автоматически переносится на следующую страницу. Но теперь нужно другое окно печати, следовательно нужно придумать что-то свое. А как сделать, чтобы текст автоматически разделялся, я и не знаю.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `QPrintPreviewWidget`, он разобъёт текст на страницы. А инструментарий по управлению настройками, в т.ч. печати, можно реализовать отдельно.

Comment: alexis031182, да, спасибо, сейчас попробовал - то что нужно.

Comment: Хотя, наверное, не совсем. Документ все равно печатается с QWebView, и перенаправляется на виджет через paintRequested. Хотел бы еще от QWebView отказаться - при печати уменьшает размер шрифта, а у меня, по задаче, размер должен быть определенным. А использование других средств - например render() - не получалось как раз из-за того что не мог разбить на страницы.

Comment: Тогда `QTextEdit` (`QTextDocument`). Html им поддерживается, хотя и в ограниченном виде, сложно-составные страницы отрендерятся вряд ли корректно.

Comment: Да, по-хорошему это надо webkit внедрять...

Comment: Andy Shevchenko webkit ведь не поддерживает печать?